# How to set up an automation framework in Github?

Tags: git, github, automation, automated-tests

I currently have 3 git repos: One for a UI test framework, one for an API, and the other for Mobile. The problem I have is that, for mobile, we have e2e testcases that first need to trigger some UI and API test cases.

Is there any way I can define UI and API code as dependencies in my mobile test cases so that when I do run a e2e mobile testcase which has UI and API pre-conditions, it will run successfully.

I am looking at gradle to handle these dependencies now, but I want to know that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach for this is the following:

- Each project needs to define its own dependencies. You use a tool like Maven (for Java projects), npm (for server-side JavaScript) or Bower (for client-side JavaScript/Web) for this.
- Each project is built on its own, using just its own dependencies.
- Each project has its own test cases, which are run when the project is built.

So in your case, a build process could look like this:

- Build the UI Test Framework and run its test cases.
- If the UI Test Framework build succeeds, build the API and run its test cases.
- If the API build succeeds, build the Mobile project and run its (unit) test cases.
- If all of the builds succeeded, deploy the application to a test server and run the e2e test cases.

This way, you have a separation of concerns, and your dependencies are set up in a clean and consistent way.

Knowing more details about your tooling and dependency management would allow a more fully featured answer.